# Why does axios get request return an empty array in the console?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch data from API using Axios, the console returns an empty array.
Here is my code. With Postman everything works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      expenses: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.retrieveExpenses();
  }

  retrieveExpenses() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/expenses').then((res) => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        this.setState({
          expenses: res.data.existingExpenses,
        });
      }
    });

    console.log(this.state.expenses);
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: please show `res.data`

Comment: Check your response in the network tab.

Comment: Because `axios.get` is asynchronous, it returns a Promise, and since `retrieveExpenses` is a synchronous function it doesn't wait for the Promise to resolve. You are just logging the current state before it's updated.

Comment: Just to add to what Drew said, to check whether any API response contains data or not, you can use `console.log` as the second argument(i.e. a callback) of `seState`, like this: 
`this.setState({expenses: res.data.existingExpenses,}, () => console.log(res.data));`